# Fail creating a SubMenu in a component with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using antd: ^3.5.4

I have a menu that contains items for user management.
When not logged the menu has a menuItem with a Link to Login page
When logged in, the menu has a SubMenu with several links including Log out

I just make a simple test on my user connected to display the link or the submenu.
I works well when all in the same file

```
    <Menu mode="horizontal">
      <Menu.Item key="home">
        <Link to={RoutesNames.HOMEPAGE}>Home</Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      {this.props.currentUserIsSignedIn ? ( 
      <SubMenu key="usermenu" title={<Avatar>A</Avatar>}> 
        <Menu.Item key="info">{this.props.currentUserEmail}</Menu.Item> 
        <Menu.Item key="logout"> 
          <Link onClick={this.props.signOutUser}>Log out</Link> 
        </Menu.Item> 
      </SubMenu> 
      ) : ( 
      <Menu.Item key="login"> 
        <Link to={RoutesNames.LOGIN}>Signin / Register</Link> 
      </Menu.Item> 
      )} 
    </Menu>
```

The problems begin when I try to create a Component UserMenu that handle this logic.
What I want to have at the end is

```
    <Menu mode="horizontal">
      <Menu.Item key="home">
        <Link to={RoutesNames.HOMEPAGE}>Home</Link>
      </Menu.Item>
      <UserMenu user={this.props.currentUser}/>
    </Menu>
```

I create my sub component UserMenu.

First I have this error:

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRootMenu' of undefined
at ProxyComponent.render (SubMenu.js:274)
```

So I updated my UserMenu component to define parentMenu

```
   <SubMenu parentMenu={this.props.menu}
```

and set the parent as parentMenu in my header file

```
   <Menu
     mode="horizontal"
     ref={el => this.menu = el}
   >
     <UserMenu menu={this.menu} user={this.props.currentUser} />
   </Menu>
```

With this menu props the subMenu is showing but I still got an error when mouseover and mouseout the submenu

```
    Uncaught TypeError: onItemHover is not a function
at onTitleMouseEnter (SubMenu.js:454)
```

For this one I have absolutely no idea what to do.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 23):

Menu passes additional props down to it's children. You need to make sure those props are passed down from your UserMenu component to the SubMenu component that you render. You can do this with an object spread operator. Example:

```
const UserMenu = (props) => {
     const {username, customProp, ...other} = props;

     return <SubMenu {...other}>
          This is my {customProp} for {username}
     </SubMenu>
}
```