# antd SubMenu "TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRootMenu' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, frontend, antd

I use antd 3.15 and GraphQL to fetch data and generate a list of SubMenu and Menu.Item inside of Menu. However, I got the error message like this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isRootMenu' of undefined` I have no idea what is wrong with my code. `isRootMenu` is not a prop listed anywhere on the doc. [ant.design/components/menu/#header](http://ant.design/components/menu/#header) and when I hardcoded all the SubMenu and Menu.List there is no problem. Can I iterate data from GraphQL to generate the  SubMenu and Menu.List?

Can someone help me with this issue, please? Thank you! Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './SideNav.scss';
import { Menu, Icon } from 'antd';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const FLOORS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
    getAllFloors {
      id
      floorName
      rooms {
        id
        roomName
        roomNumber
        roomDescription
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default class SideNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Menu theme="light" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
        <Query query={FLOORS_QUERY}>
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <h4> loading... </h4>;
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(data);
            return (
              <React.Fragment>
                {data.getAllFloors.map((floor) => (
                  <SubMenu
                    key={floor.id}
                    title={
                      <span>
                        <Icon type="plus" />
                        <span>{floor.floorName}</span>
                      </span>
                    }
                  >
                    <React.Fragment>
                      {floor.rooms.map((room) => (
                        <Menu.Item key={room.id}>{room.roomNumber}</Menu.Item>
                      ))}
                    </React.Fragment>
                  </SubMenu>
                ))}
              </React.Fragment>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you use `isRootMenu` in your code?

Comment: `isRootMenu` is not a prop listed anywhere on the doc. https://ant.design/components/menu/#header @Vencovsky

Comment: do you use that in some other part of your code?

Comment: @Vencovsky I use this component in the App.tsx and when I hardcoded all the SubMenu, and Menu.Item there is no problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail creating a SubMenu in a component with antd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573609/fail-creating-a-submenu-in-a-component-with-antd)

Comment: @Eddy Borja  Can you take a look at this question? I saw you answered a similar question earlier, but I still can't figure out this issue from your previous answer... Thank you!

Comment: I am running into the same problem using 3.15.2

Answer (score 6):

You should pass the props to the submenu.

```
  const CustomComponent = (props) => (
    <Menu.SubMenu title='SubMenu' {...props}>
      <Menu.Item>SubMenuItem</Menu.Item>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
  )
```

so a solution to your question would be to do the following;

1. move the query outside of the containing menu
2. pass the props to the SubMenu

```
  const FloorMapSubMenu = ({ id, floorName, rooms, ...other }) => {
  return (
    <Menu.SubMenu
      key={id}
      title={
        <span>
          <Icon type="plus" />
          <span>{floorName}</span>
        </span>
      }
      {...other} // notice the other props, this is were the 'isRootMenu' is injected from the <Menu> children
    >
      <React.Fragment>
        {rooms.map((room) => (
          <Menu.Item key={room.id}>{room.roomNumber}</Menu.Item>
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    </Menu.SubMenu>
  )
}

class SideNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Query query={FLOORS_QUERY}>
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          if (loading) return <h4> loading... </h4>
          if (error) console.log(error)
          console.log(data)
          return (
            <Menu theme='light' defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode='inline'>
              {data.getAllFloors.map((floor, i) => (
                <FloorMapSubMenu key={i} id={floor.id} floorName={floor.floorName} rooms={floor.rooms} />
              ))}
            </Menu>
          )
        }}
      </Query>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found out the Ant design **SubMenu** needs to use the parent to check some properties like **isRootMenu** at

SubMenu.js:260

```js
getPopupContainer = props.parentMenu.isRootMenu ? props.parentMenu.props.getPopupContainer : function (triggerNode) {
     return triggerNode.parentNode; 
}
```

In order to solve it you need to manually pass parent props into SubMenu like

```
<Menu.SubMenu {...this.props}/>
```

to solve the problem. Hope this helps u

Related Github issue item https://github.com/react-component/menu/issues/255

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue while trying to add a `<div>` as a child of `Menu`. I just added an empty `Menu.Item` as the first child of my menu, and the error went away.

```
<Menu>
  <Menu.Item style={{display: 'none'}} />
  <div>...</div>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. It seems Antd does not allow to place arbitrary components into a `Menu/SubMenu`. My guess is that `Menu.Item` needs to get some props, which are passed from `Menu/SubMenu` to its children.

So you can either create a custom component that passes all props down, or **remove the inner `<React.Fragment>` declaration** (the one that is inside the `SubMenu`), which is not needed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work by putting the `<Query>` Component at the top:

```
<Query query={FLOORS_QUERY}>
          {({ loading, error, data }) => {
            if (loading) return <Spin />;
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(data);
            return (
              <Menu theme="light" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']} mode="inline">
                {data.getAllFloors.map((floor) => (
                  <SubMenu
                    key={floor.id}
                    title={
                      <Link to="/{floor.id}">
                        <span>
                          <Icon type="plus" />
                          <span>{floor.floorName}</span>
                        </span>
                      </Link>
                    }
                  >
                    {floor.rooms.map((room) => (
                      <Menu.Item key={room.id} onClick={this.showRoomProfile}>
                        {room.roomNumber}
                      </Menu.Item>
                    ))}
                  </SubMenu>
                ))}
              </Menu>
            );
          }}
        </Query>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Typescript definitions the childrens of Menu should be of kind Item, SubMenu, ItemGroup or Divider. If you must place a different component on the Header, wrap the Menu and the desired component on a Header component component as [such](https://codesandbox.io/s/d0n7j):

```
import { Layout } from 'antd';

const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;

<Layout>
    <Layout.Header>
    <div className="logo" />
    <Menu>
      <Menu.Item key="1">nav 1</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="2">nav 2</Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
  <Layout.Header>
</Layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into the same issue. But my issues was I have using ternary condition to show some menu's dynamically inside part used the <></> element. That caused me this issue. Once removed that everything work fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32529673)